# Getting ImageMagick convert to not write out extra info

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick's convert to resize some .png files, the problem is that convert seems to be writing some extra info to the .png:

```
EXtdate:create 2012-11-26T19:50:31-08:001
```

The problem is that if the source image didn't change, a new scaled down image is produced that is identical to the old one, but it has this extra time/date info and it's causing git to think all the files have changed.

Is there a way to keep convert from writing out this addition meta info so subsequent resizing won't show the files as changed is the source image didn't change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem was adding:

```
+set date:create +set date:modify
```

The -strip  option was not removing the embedded data, but this does.

Comment: Both `+set` and `-strip` options worked fine here. strip is a lot more aggressive, since it strips out a *lot* of metadata, but that can have its uses. Create date was my only issue, so `+set`was enough for me

Answer (score 6):

You're searching for the -strip parameter, ie:

```
convert infile.png -resize 100x100 -strip outfile.png
```